# c# - how to set text in textbox to show hint when textbox is empty?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, textbox

I am using `<asp:TextBox>` not HTML textbox and I want to display hint text.

Is there any way to achieve that?

I have tried for making static text and color it gray but not getting how to make it empty when cursor get focus to that textbox.

Comment: You could use JavaScript to clear the text on focus.

Answer (score 9):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" placeholder="Hint Text"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use a ASP.NET [WaterMark TextBox](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/TextBoxWatermark/TextBoxWatermark.aspx)

It is in [Ajax Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/download.ashx)

Answer (score 3):

You, can give in Code behind like follows

```
textBox.Attributes.Add(“onfocus”, “clearText(this,’” + defaultText + “‘)”);
```

And also refer to [this](http://chillijam.co.uk/2008/06/03/hint-text-in-aspnet-textbox-controls/) to know more.

Answer (score 3):

You can using "placeholder" properties for textbox.

**Example**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="233px" placeholder="Search"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the HTML5 placeholder attribute for that. The downside is that it's only supported by some browsers. Fortunately you have JQuery Placeholder to the rescue. This plugin makes the placeholder behavior available for unsupported browsers.

Check it out here [JQuery Placeholder](https://github.com/danielstocks/jQuery-Placeholder)

Answer (score 0):

text input watermarks using javascript.
refer this it might help u
http://naspinski.net/post/Text-Input-Watermarks-using-Javascript-%28IE-Compatible%29.aspx

Answer (score -1):

just add property `placeholder="HintText"` in your asp textbox

Comment: How is your answer different to the other three answers which suggest using the placeholder attribute?